# How do I return a value from inside a loop?

Tags: ruby, rexml, do-loops

I am trying to read an XML file and store the structure into an array of objects. Here is my code:

```
class Bike
    attr_accessor :id, :color, :name
    def initialize(id, color, name)
        @id = id
        @color = color
        @name = name
    end
end

---x---snip---x---

rules.root.each_element do |node1|
    case node1.name
    when "Bike"
        bike = Bike.new(node1.attributes['id'], node1.attributes['color'], { |bike_elem| bike_elem.text.chomp if bike_elem.name == "name"})
        bikes.push bike
    end
end
```

However, the last element is not fetching the value alone. It is fetching the whole tag. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think that is a valid Ruby expression.

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with iteration (or, "loop" in your words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code block `{ |bike_elem| bike_elem.text.chomp if bike_elem.name == "name" }`
doesn't seem to make sense inside the `new` parameter list.

Where does `bike_elem` come from? This is not valid Ruby in this context.

It's hard to give an answer here without knowing what your XML looks like. 
But I would recommend using a XML library like Nokogiri, libxml, and then parse out 
the name before you do the `new`.  Try using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

```
 rules.root.each_element do |node1|
  case node1.name
    when "Bike"
      name = node1.attributes[....]
      bike = Bike.new(node1.attributes['id'], node1.attributes['color'],name )
      bikes.push bike
    end
 end
```

Comment: isn't bike_elem.text.chomp the last one that is evaluated?